# Unknown Host Exception with GAE app when trying to connect to a website

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, htmlunit

I am learning how to scrape using htmlUnit in Java 8 and I am trying to deploy an app to the google app engine that will scrape certain websites every so often. I am developing the app in Eclipse and it works as expected when run locally, however after deploying to GAE my app is no longer able to make connections to any websites.

```
 try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

      webClient.setCookieManager(new CookieManager() {
          protected int getPort(final java.net.URL url) {
          final int r = super.getPort(url);
          return r != -1 ? r : 80;
          }
          });  

      final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com");
      }

  catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());         
  }
```

The error occurs at "webClient.getPage(....)"

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
```

Partial stack trace:

```
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.recreation.gov
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UrlFetchWebConnection.getResponse(UrlFetchWebConnection.java:162)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1394)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1312)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:396)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:317)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:465)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at pack.HelloAppEngine.doGet(HelloAppEngine.java:49)
[s~permitseacherbpd/20180314t161057.408306947286449649].<stderr>:   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
```

This error occurs for any website I try to access and is NOT exclusive to htmlUnit as I have encountered this error before in other projects. Why can I not connect after deploying to the app engine?

Comment: Which type of GAE container are you deploying to? Is this behavior (initiating outgoing connections) allowed?

Comment: HtmlUnit (HttpClient) does not use the proxy setup of the jvm. You have to provide this information to HtmlUnit itself (see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: App Engine for Java 8 doesn't require a proxy.  Using the stock java.net facilities, I'm able to use the `ProxySelector` to verify that App Engine uses a `DIRECT` connection and I'm able to fetch the content from `https://www.google.com`.

```
response.getWriter().append("\nProxy for https://www.google.com:");
for (Proxy proxy : ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI.create("https://www.google.com"))) {
        response.getWriter().append("\n  " + proxy);
}
response.getWriter().append("\n" + URI.create("https://www.google.com").toURL().getContent());
```

Answer (score 1):

My little test servlet started to throw similar `UnknownHostException`s too.  I came across [#63916008](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63916008) which links to the [`<url-stream-handler>` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#url-stream-handler) that notes (emphasis mine)

> For the Java 8 runtime, the default value is native, which means that standard Java network classes use the standard Java HTTP(S) transport, as described in Java 8 runtime vs Java 7 behavior. **This setting requires the app to have billing enabled**, otherwise the following runtime errors will result from requests:
>
> java.net.UnknownHostException
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException
>   java.io.IOException

Configure your `appengine-web.xml` to use `urlfetch` and your problem should be solved!